# Operators in ruby on rails not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wrote this function:

```
  if params[:id] > @max
   @page = @max
    end
```

Here `@max` is an integer, and the value of `params[:id]` isn't `nil`.

It says there is a problem in the first line, and problem is:

> undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

It doesn't recognize `>` as an operator. Why is it so?

Comment: Are you sure the value of params[:id] isn't nil? That error means it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't recognize it as an operator on the `NilClass` like it says. `params[:id]` must be nil. Check your Rails logs for the list of parameters coming into the request. My guess is that the param is named differently than you think. Try `if params[:id].present? && params[:id] > @max` or `params[:id].to_i > @max` to work around the exception.

Comment: `params[:id].to_i` will just mask the problem, as `nil.to_i` returns 0; it could be very dangerous if `0` is a valid ID for some object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `params[:id]` *is* `nil`. That's what that error means. Perhaps you wanted `params['id']` instead? If you have access to the console for your running app, try `p params, params[:id]` and make your request again to see what values there are, and the value of `params[:id]`.